# Вывод новой информации в парсере

Tags: python, python-3.x

Сори за возможно плохо сформулированный вопрос, но нужна подсказка. Как сделать парсер данных, который обновляется раз в секунду. Тоесть есть сайт и последний номер айтема, например, 48DSUdnSDds8Ds8snd. Но в любую секунду могут добавиться новые айтемы со своим уникальным номером. Возникает лишь сложность в том, как мне выводить в скрипте исключительно новые данные? Я думал присваивать последний номер айтема переменной, но это не работает корректно, так как за одну секунду может быть добавлено более 10 айтемов и будет неккоректно выведена информация

```
from unittest import result
from solana.rpc.api import Client
import chime 

wallet = ''
solana_client = Client("")
solana_fm = 'https://hyper.solana.fm/v3/transfers/'
def main():
    response_node = (solana_client.get_signatures_for_address(wallet, limit=1))
    result_node = (response_node.get('result'))
    if result_node == (solana_client.get_signatures_for_address(wallet, limit=1)).get('result'):
         print('Nothing New')
    else:
        chime.success()
        print('Smth New)')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        main()
```

Comment: укажите сайт с которым вы работаете, покажите ваши попытки (слова "я пытался" не котируются)

Comment: Код предоставте. Мне лично не понятна причина не корректной работы вашего парсера.

Comment: Отредактировал, но думаю это врятли поможет

Comment: В функций main  два запроса на solana_client которые отличаются между собой по времени по этому не корректно работает.

Comment: В функций main оставьте  один запрос на solana_client (запоминаете его для отслеживаня изменнений нужной нам информаций)  в if запрос уберите.

Comment: Я не очень понимаю, как я тогда должен проверять, что появились изменения

Comment: Создайте некую переменную,  которая будет запоминать данные для отслехивания изменений пусть будет tmp. В функций делаем запрос и обрабатываем его (result), сравниваем result и tmp если есть изменения tmp = result и т.д.